# ArangoDB: AQL query to get all edges between two specific nodes

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have a document collection 'node' and an edge collection 'attribute'. 
I am trying to get all edges in 'attribute' collection from: 'node/582148' to: 'node/582016'.

The simplest AQL query I've been able to devise is the following:

```
FOR v, e, p IN OUTBOUND 'node/582148' `attribute`
    FILTER e._to == 'node/582016'
    RETURN p
```

Is there really no way to do this in one, like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN OUTBOUND 'node/582148' TO 'node/582016' `attribute` RETURN p
```

It's only possible to use the 'TO' keyword with SHORTEST_PATH. To clarify: **I am only interested in direct paths (1 edge) between the nodes**

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using graph traversal i would recommend to use the following AQL query to get all outgoing edges, which is filtering by the target vertex key:

```
FOR v, e IN OUTBOUND 'node/582148' `attribute`
FILTER v._key == '582016'
RETURN e
```

Another approach is to address the edge as a document with attributes _from and _to without graph traversal:

```
FOR e IN `attribute`
FILTER e._from == 'node/582148' && e._to == 'node/582016'
RETURN e
```

Comment: thanks. in the first example, what if **v** is not of type 'node', shouldn't I add  FILTER v._key == 'node/582016'?

Comment: No, v._key should only contain the key of the document, not its collection name.

Comment: `_key` stores the document key only, e.g. `"1234"`. Document keys are not even allowed to contain slashes: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/DataModeling/NamingConventions/DocumentKeys.html `_id` is a concatenation of collection name, a forward slash and the document key, e.g. `"node/1234"`.

Comment: Regarding the Traversal... Do you think there is any way how to further optimize such a query? When I am using depth of 1..5 my query takes around 28sec with 9 vertices collections and 16 edge collections, with only 11764 objects in total (entities+links).
I know finding all paths between 2 nodes is complex task, but I am looking for any optimization I could make.
In further project I will need depth even like 5..10 which will be even more complex.

Comment: @DominikFranek I suspect the new PRUNE function (new in 3.5?) will help you in the traversal case.  See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LVeeC0ciCQ